# How to parse datetime for use in highchart graph?

Tags: php, highcharts

Here  i got timestamp value

```
$user_array1[] = $val['timestamp'];
$graph_data1 ='';  
if(is_array($user_array1))
{
   $graph_data1 = implode(',',$user_array1);
}
```

Output when i `print_r($graph_data1);`

I got

> ,2014-05-26 00:43:45,2014-05-26 00:43:52,2014-05-26 00:43:592014-05-26
>   00:43:19,2014-05-26 00:43:24,2014-05-26 00:43:27,2014-05-26
>   00:43:30,2014-05-26 00:43:34,2014-05-26 00:43:37,2014-05-26
>   00:43:41,2014-05-26 00:43:45,2014-05-26 00:43:52,2014-05-26
>   00:43:59,2014-05-26 00:44:11

Highchart side :

```
categories: [<?php echo $graph_data1 ?> ]
```

it does not show any things.

Comment: try to add quotes on your implode so that each date has quotes, sample: `$graph_data1 = "'".implode("','", $user_array1)."'";`

Comment: perfect ,thanks  –  kevinabelita

Comment: plz show it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current format of data, your string are considered malformed, and therefore incorrect for input in highcharts. You must format it correctly fist. Consider this example:

```
$graph_data1 = "'".implode("','", $user_array1)."'";
```

Should output something like this:

> '2014-05-26 00:43:45','2014-05-26 00:43:45','2014-05-26 00:43:45' ... etc ...